# Question regarding how to find the coordinate vector of a transition matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Given that A= $\begin{bmatrix}
1.5 & -1 & -.5\\
-.5 & 2 & .5\\
.5 & 1 & 5/2
\end{bmatrix}$ is the standrad matrix for $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ relative to B and the transition matrix $P=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

Find $[v_B]$ and $[T(v)]_B$ where $[v]_{B'}=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$

I know that to find $[v]_{B'}$ we simply multiply $[v]_B$ by the transition matrix P.
What I am not sure is how to get $[T(v)]_B$. Any help is appreciated.